# Python: Use numpy.nanmean() for selected intervals of an axis

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have a 4D matrix, A (with shape [251,6,60,141]) that contains a lot of NaNs. I would like to reshape this matrix into another matrix B (with shape [73,6,60,141]). In other words, in axis=0, I want to take numpy.nanmean() of irregular interval steps. Is there a way to do this efficiently?

I hope that the loop in the code below illustrates my desire, but I don't think it works, because it ends in a (seemingly) endless loop of RuntimeWarnings:

"/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/lib/nanfunctions.py:598: RuntimeWarning: Mean of empty slice
  warnings.warn("Mean of empty slice", RuntimeWarning)"

```
import numpy as np

A = np.full(([251,6,60,141]), np.nan)    # Create matrix A full of NaNs
# Assign some random values in random grid boxes in A
A[0, 1, 2, 3] = 4
A[1, 2, 3, 4] = 5
A[2, 3, 4, 5] = 6
A[3, 4, 5, 6] = 7

# Create the 1D array of the number of rows I want to average together in each interval
intvl = [0, 5, 2, 2, 1, 6, 5, 4, 1, 6, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 5, 6, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 6, 3, 6, 3, 1, 6, 3, 6, 1, 4, 6, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 4, 2, 5, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 6, 4, 2, 3, 5, 5, 5, 7, 4, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 3, 5, 3, 2, 7, 5, 3, 5, 3, 3, 2]
# Sum the intvl array stepwise
intvl_cs = np.cumsum(intvl)

# Loop to perform the interval summation 
B = np.full(([len(intvl),6,60,141]), np.nan)    # Create the matrix B, intially full of NaNs
for b in np.arange(len(intvl)-1):
    for L in np.arange(6):
        for i in np.arange(60):
            for j in np.arange(141):
                B[b,L,i,j] = np.nanmean(A[intvl_cs[b]:intvl_cs[b+1],L,i,j])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To improve performance you can vectorize the summation when you replace the entire loop block with

```
for b in np.arange(len(intvl)-1):
    B[b, ...] = np.nanmean(A[intvl_cs[b]:intvl_cs[b+1], ...], axis=0)
```

And make it a little bit more readable if you do

```
B = np.zeros((len(intvl_cs) - 1, 6, 60, 141))
# no need to initialize to `nan` if we are touching all values anyways

for b, (start, stop) in enumerate(zip(intvl_cs[:-1], intvl_cs[1:])):
    B[b, ...] = np.nanmean(A[start:stop, ...], axis=0)
```

On my machine the computation finishes in a fraction of a second.

Comment: I'm not sure I buy your `A[154:155, ...]` is empty argument -- it's _not_ empty, it has shape (1, 6, 60, 141).  ISTM the reason that we're getting the warning is because that's what nanmean _does_ when passed an array of all-NaNs, because the denominator is zero.

Comment: Wow! Thank you guys! That was a wonderful and elegant solution.